# How to improve Using RANK() top 2 results into unique columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Here is the SQL 9(i) code written to show results 1 and 2 in their own columns.  Is there a more efficient way to write this?

```
select 
  sc1.COIL as COIL1
, sc1.DEFECT as DEFECT1
, sc2.DEFECT as DEFECT2
FROM
      (select
            COIL, DEFECT
            , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY COIL ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC) RNK
            from NOVELIS.F406, NOVELIS.F408 where   F406_DEFECT_CODE = F408_REJECT_CODE
            GROUP BY COIL, DEFECT
        )sc1
    , (select
            COIL, DEFECT
            , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY COIL ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC) RNK
            from NOVELIS.F406, NOVELIS.F408 where   F406_DEFECT_CODE = F408_REJECT_CODE
            GROUP BY COIL, DEFECT
        )sc2

WHERE 
sc1.RNK = 1 
and sc2.RNK = 2 
and sc1.COIL = sc2.COIL
```

Comment: What will happen when two coils will have the same, greatest weight? The RANK() function will give the same weight to both, so your scalar subqueries will result in errors. What is the business requirement in that case? What if THREE coils are tied for greatest weight? **Note that this issue will afflict the two answers posted so far.** If two coils are the same greatest weight, only one of them will be shown in the DEFECT1 column, and the NOTHING will go in the second column since RANK = 2 will not be assigned in that case.

Comment: Really good question.  I will explore this with the quality team.  Is there a way to break the tie?  It does not matter which is first, second or third.

Comment: Yes, and it's easy - use ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK(). It does exactly what you need. If you want a tie-breaker you can add it to the ORDER BY clause: `ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC, DELIVERY_DATE DESC` will order by weight, and then in the case of ties it will take the two most recently delivered coils. Or whatever else you need/want to add in the ordering as a tie-breaker. This applies to the solutions offered, too.

Comment: Okay .... there were 64 ties out of 45,000 records returned.  I just introduced the record ID into the query (PARTITION BY COIL ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC, REC_ID DESC).  This worked fine.  Thank you once again.

Comment: Perfect - if REC_ID is a unique value, then ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK would all return the same values (with that ORDER BY clause), so it is not necessary to change to ROW_NUMBER. RANK will work equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and use 1 derived table

```
SELECT    sc1.COIL AS COIL1,
          MAX(CASE WHEN RNK = 1 THEN sc1.DEFECT END) AS DEFECT1,
          MAX(CASE WHEN RNK = 2 THEN sc1.DEFECT END) AS DEFECT2
FROM
(
    SELECT COIL,
           DEFECT,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY COIL ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC) RNK
    FROM   NOVELIS.F406
           --practice using joins
           INNER JOIN NOVELIS.F408 ON F406_DEFECT_CODE = F408_REJECT_CODE
    --not sure you need the group by here
) sc1
GROUP BY sc1.COIL
```

Comment: Jamie,  Thank you.  I have been struggling with this for a while.  Thank you for the quick answer.  Your solution has actually gone into production.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reading the tables twice, just read them once and pivot out the results:-

```
select 
coil,
max (case when rnk=1 then defect else null end) defect1,
max (case when rnk=2 then defect else null end) defect2
FROM (
select 
COIL, DEFECT, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY COIL ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC) RNK
from NOVELIS.F406
inner join NOVELIS.F408 on F406_DEFECT_CODE = F408_REJECT_CODE
) sc
WHERE 
sc.RNK <= 2 

group by coil
```

Comment: Peter,  Thank you as well.  These solutions are much more elegant and efficient.